# pandas - keep only True values after groupby a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on a DataFrame with User_IDs, DateTime objects and other information, like the following extract:

```
User_ID;Latitude;Longitude;Datetime
222583401;41.4020375;2.1478710;2014-07-06 20:49:20
287280509;41.3671346;2.0793115;2013-01-30 09:25:47
329757763;41.5453577;2.1175164;2012-09-25 08:40:59
189757330;41.5844998;2.5621569;2013-10-01 11:55:20
624921653;41.5931846;2.3030671;2013-07-09 20:12:20
414673119;41.5550136;2.0965829;2014-02-24 20:15:30
414673119;41.5550136;2.0975829;2014-02-24 20:16:30
414673119;41.5550136;2.0985829;2014-02-24 20:17:30
```

I've grouped Users with:

```
g = df.groupby(['User_ID','Datetime'])
```

and then check for no-single DataTime objects:

```
df = df.groupby('User_ID')['Datetime'].apply(lambda g: len(g)>1)
```

I've obtained the following boolean DataFrame:

```
User_ID
189757330    False
222583401    False
287280509    False
329757763    False
414673119     True
624921653    False
Name: Datetime, dtype: bool
```

which is fine for my purposes to keep only User_ID with a True masked value. Now I would like to keep only the User_ID values associated to the True values, and write them to a new DataFrame with `pandas.to_csv`, for instance. The expected DataFrame would contain only the User_ID with more than one DateTime object:

```
User_ID;Latitude;Longitude;Datetime
414673119;41.5550136;2.0965829;2014-02-24 20:15:30
414673119;41.5550136;2.0975829;2014-02-24 20:16:30
414673119;41.5550136;2.0985829;2014-02-24 20:17:30
```

How may I have access to the boolean values for each User_ID? Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assign the result of `df.groupby('User_ID')['Datetime'].apply(lambda g: len(g)>1)` to a variable so you can perform boolean indexing and then use the index from this to call `isin` and filter your orig df:

```
In [366]:

users = df.groupby('User_ID')['Datetime'].apply(lambda g: len(g)>1)
users

Out[366]:
User_ID
189757330    False
222583401    False
287280509    False
329757763    False
414673119     True
624921653    False
Name: Datetime, dtype: bool

In [367]:   
users[users]

Out[367]:
User_ID
414673119    True
Name: Datetime, dtype: bool

In [368]:
users[users].index

Out[368]:
Int64Index([414673119], dtype='int64')

In [361]:
df[df['User_ID'].isin(users[users].index)]

Out[361]:
     User_ID   Latitude  Longitude            Datetime
5  414673119  41.555014   2.096583 2014-02-24 20:15:30
6  414673119  41.555014   2.097583 2014-02-24 20:16:30
7  414673119  41.555014   2.098583 2014-02-24 20:17:30
```

You can then call `to_csv` on the above as normal

Comment: Great! Thanks! I was missing the variable assignment to perform the masking, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure you have no duplicate entries:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

then, figure out the counts for each:

```
counts = df.groupby('User_ID').Datetime.count()
```

finally, figure out where the indexes overlap:

```
df[df.User_ID.isin(counts[counts > 1].index)]
```